# Como atualizar branch pela master?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Estou trabalhando numa branch mas aparentemente um dev já mecheu nela e acabou quebrando uma parte do sistema, queria atualizar a essa branch com a master mas não mesclar essa branch com a master e sim atualizar tirar todo o codigo antigo e zerar ela a partir da master.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais fácil que conheço seria utilizando um *force push*, no caso de branches remotas.

```sh
# Caso você tenha a branch local atualmente, remova:
git branch -D nome-da-branch

git checkout master

# Atualize a master para garantir que você tenha a versão mais atualizada
# Se necessário, adicione "-u origin master" ao final do comando
git pull

# Crie a branch novamente com um checkout a partir da master
git checkout -b nome-da-branch 

# Faça um force-push, sobrescrevendo a branch remota com sua branch local atual 
# (Que foi recriada a partir da master)
git push -f -u origin nome-da-branch
```

Em casos de branches locais, basta deletar e recriar a branch a partir da `master`.

Caso esteja usando *GitHub*, *GitLab* ou similares, você pode também deletar a branch e criar novamente a partir da master a partir do site.